# Unable to render Parent record in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura

I need to render parent name in a LWC that is called from an aura component.  I thought I had it working but the field is blank.  I also added a controller thinking that was my issue but still not pulling the parent id in.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride" access="global" >  
    <c:CreateLeasePaymentTerm></c:CreateLeasePaymentTerm>
</aura:component>
```

LWC HTML

```
     <lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="Lease_Payment_Term__c"
     onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit}>
     <lightning-messages>
     </lightning-messages>
    <lightning-output-field field-name="Lease__c">
    </lightning-output-field>
    <lightning-input type="text" name="Lease" readonly label="Lease" value={leaseName}>
    </lightning-input>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>
```

LWC JS

```
import { LightningElement,wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import getLPTDetails from '@salesforce/apex/CreateLeasePaymentTerm.getLease';
import Lease_Payment from '@salesforce/schema/Lease_Payment__c';
import Lease_Payment_Term from '@salesforce/schema/Lease_Payment_Term__c';

@api recordId;
@api LPT;
@track leaseName;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: Lease_Payment_Term })
objectInfo;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: Lease_Payment })
objectInfo1;

 @wire(getLPTDetails, { LeasePayId: '$recordId' })
consList({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.LPT = { ...data };
        this.leaseName = this.LPT.Lease__c.Name; 
        window.console.log(' this.leaseName  ===> '+JSON.stringify( this.leaseName ));
    } else if (error) {
        console.error('ERROR => ', error);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
 @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Lease_Payment_Term__c getLease(Id LeasePayId){
        return [SELECT Lease__c, Lease__r.Name FROM Lease_Payment_Term__c WHERE Id =:LeasePayId LIMIT 1];
    }
```

Comment: why are you not using the `lighting-input-field` to populate the parent field?

Comment: @rahul will that populate the field?  I thought this would make the lookup field available but not actually pull in the parent value.

Comment: @rahul, using <lightning-input-field field-name="Lease__c" ></lightning-input-field> does show the lookup field but it does not populated the lookup with the actual parent value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a quick action and reference the component in the QA and removed `record-id={recordId}` from the lwc html file and this resolved the issue.